# shell_exec to run a Perl file

Tags: php, perl, apache

```
$cmdOutput = shell_exec("perl run_single_test/hello.pl");
echo "the command output = $cmdOutput";
```

This causes the file `hello.pl` to execute and print "hello world back to page". But

```
shell_exec("perl run_single_test/test_single_run.pl -s \"$testSuiteName\" -t \"$testName\" -i $time");
```

does not get executed. I echoed the command to screen and ran it on terminal, the Perl script executed perfectly. `test_single_run.pl` creates a log file and copies a few files.

What am I missing?

Comment: Are the permissions on `test_single_run.pl` the same as they are on `hello.pl`?

Comment: @daxim: [`shell_exec`](http://us.php.net/shell_exec) is a builtin PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the answer.
The `test_single_run.pl` was modifying a few files in other directories.
I got to know that apache runs the perl script as a different user . In my case it was `wwwrun` and thus lacked the permissions to operate on other files.

Changed the configuration file `uid.conf` to make apache run the perl script as my user. And it worked